# .htaccess not redirecting to error page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'd created `.htaccess` file to remove canonical issue with my site.
Here's the code:

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.reddyclasses.com/error.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(reddyclasses\.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.reddyclasses.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html      
order deny,allow
```

Is this code is correct? Also, my site is not redirecting to error page if I do enter a wrong url like `http://reddyclasses.com/err`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't redirect because you redirect all traffic to index.php so http://reddyclasses.com/err does exist. You need to trigger 404 error from PHP itself in this case..

Comment: which line is doing so (redirecting all traffic to `index.php`) in `.htaccess`

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: okay. should i replace that code with this one: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php\ HTTP/` 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]`?

Comment: it's hard to tell without knowing how your website process data. Probably it take's that query and determine which page to open next. I don't think changing it like that would solve problem.